# Ionic 2 : Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nav' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I just do not understand the error, why is that it cannot read the property 'nav'. I am confuse. Hope anyone can help me and explain to me the error, here is the error :

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';

import { AccountPage } from '../pages/account/account';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('nav') nav:Nav;

  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor( public nativeStorage: NativeStorage, public googlePlus: GooglePlus, platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

      platform.ready().then(() => {

      let env = this;

      this.googlePlus.trySilentLogin({
        'scopes': '', // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
        'webClientId': 'webClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
        'offline': true
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        this.nav.push(AccountPage);
        this.splashScreen.hide();
      }, function (error){
        this.nav.push(LoginPage);
        this.splashScreen.hide();
      });

      statusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using standard functions, so the `this` keyword gets overwritten, and references that function instead of the component. To avoid that issue, you need to use **arrow functions**, like this:

```
// ...

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('nav') nav:Nav;

  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(public nativeStorage: NativeStorage, 
                public googlePlus: GooglePlus, 
                public platform: Platform, 
                public statusBar: StatusBar, 
                public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {

        let env = this;

        this.googlePlus.trySilentLogin({
            'scopes': '', // optional, space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
            'webClientId': 'webClientId.apps.googleusercontent.com', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
            'offline': true
        })
        .then(
            data => {   // <---------------- Here!
                this.nav.push(AccountPage);
                this.splashScreen.hide();
            }, 
            error => {  // <---------------- Here!
                this.nav.push(LoginPage);
                this.splashScreen.hide();
            });

        statusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)